# Initial value of Picker

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I know that I can set initial value of UIPickerView with this code

```
[pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

But how to do that if I have an array with string objects ?. Lets's say that I have an array like  this

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray initWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third" ...... nil];
```

Now what I want is if I choose the third color in table view then the picker view initial value to be "third"

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have a table view that displays the following data:

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray initWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third" ...... nil];
```

and want to set the initial value of the picker view to the index of the selected item in the table view.

You can achieve that using the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [pickerView selectRow:indexPath.row inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: That make sense, but the picker is in different view.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain that in your question? Is this different view displayed when a row is selected in the table view?